# Symmetric, Relatively Compact Open Neighborhoods of $1$

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group. If $V$ is a symmetric, relatively compact open neighborhood of $1$, why is it true that $\overline{V}^n \subseteq V \cdot V^n$ for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$?

Comment: Is it enough to say that $\overline{V}^n = \overline{V^n}$ in this case?

Comment: @DanielFischer Perhaps, but I don't see it.

Comment: I'm working under the assumption that "locally compact" implies Hausdorff. If not, I'm not sure whether it works. By continuity of multiplication, $\overline{V}^n$ is compact, hence closed. And trivially it contains $V^n$, so $\overline{V^n}\subset\overline{V}^n$. Conversely, with the multiplication map $\mu\colon G^n\to G$, we have $V\times\ldots\times V\subset \mu^{-1}(\overline{V^n})$. The RHS is closed, so $\overline{V}\times \ldots \times \overline{V} \subset \mu^{-1}(\overline{V^n})$, thus $\overline{V}^n \subset \overline{V^n}$ (this part doesn't need the compactness of $\overline{V}$).